# Retrofit API Post call returning error 500, works well with Postman

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am trying to consume a rest API using retrofit 2, i have been able to consume some endpoint but the sign up endpoint keeps returning http 500 error code but works fine when tested with postman.
  `@POST("auth/signup/")
    Call<SignUpResponce> addUser(@Body SignUpCreds signUpCreds);`

This is the sign up credentials

```
public class SignUpCreds {
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;


public SignUpCreds(String username, String email, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

This is the sign up response

```
public class SignUpResponce {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;
@SerializedName("dateRegistered")
@Expose
private Integer dateRegistered;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Integer getDateRegistered() {
    return dateRegistered;
}

public void setDateRegistered(Integer dateRegistered) {
    this.dateRegistered = dateRegistered;
}
```

}

Json object in postman

```
{
"username": "doe2jane",
"email": "jane@yahoo.com",
"password": "janedoe"
```

}

Json Response in postman

```
{
"id": 7,
"username": "doe2jane",
"email": "jane@yahoo.com",
"password": "janedoe",
"dateRegistered": 1499870604166
```

}

My signUpCred

`SignUpCreds creds = new SignUpCreds(username, email, password);`

Retrofit Class:

```
public class AuthUtil {
private static Retrofit sRetrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getRetrofit(String url){
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    if (sRetrofit == null){
        sRetrofit  = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return sRetrofit;
}
```

}

Postman screen: https://ibb.co/gNwrQF

Comment: Could you post the whole code for SignUpCreds? Also is the `/` at the end of the `auth/signup/` necessary?

Comment: That's the whole code for the class, it only has a constructor and fields

Comment: Field naming is non-trivial when you use `@Body Type  name`

Comment: I have updated the SignUpCreds class, i used jsonschematopojo to generate the class. Removing the blackslash at the end of `auth/signup` changed nothing.

Comment: hmmm. Everything looks ok with that, you should post your Postman request or (ideally) look at what your server error logs say

Comment: I have include a link to the picture of my postman screen, to the best of my knowledge everything is okay, dont know why its not working. Seems theres no other way of passing raw json in the body of a request in retrofit

Comment: 500 error you are getting is because either the data you are passing through object is wrong or internal server error but as you said its working well in postman so check body of ur request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, please the error logs.

500 Internal server error simply mean some exception has been thrown in server and request not completed as expected. So I guess its may be some null pointer exception and the reason might be your invalid JSON or your code logic I am not sure about it.

Comment: The api call was successful but returning 500, I have tested with same values on postman and it was successful.

Comment: Turns out the problem was from the endpoint, received the right value but kept on returning 500, hopefully the developer would fix it soon.

Comment: @UmarKhattap I am having the same problem, can you explain what was the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: sometimes, this also occurs when an android client, doesn't define the `Content-Type` on the header or maybe the server side doesn't accept particular type from android, so the error from android shows 500 code.

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-add-custom-request-header

Answer (score 0):

1. Sometimes, this also occurs when an android client, doesn't define the 
   `Content-Type` on the header `@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")` or
2. Maybe the server side doesn't accept particular type from
   android (client side), so the 500 error code thrown.

Similar problem I found, when our server using laravel, and having this [`auth:api middleware`](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-passport-authapi-middleware-acts-as-web-auth-middleware?page=1#reply=374794). The android side doesn't explicitly set the headers with `Content-type: application/json`, the 500 code error returned, instead of having a 401 response code.

[image: e.g: invalid auth token from postman]